# List of Keys being passed to Reduce Task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any way to determine no of key's processed by reduce task? Actually i have set no of reducer as 7  in job but out of these reducers , 6 are executing within second but last reducer is taking hours to complete. It looks like key is not getting distributed uniformly over reducer. So wanted to check how many keys are being processed by single reducer task?

I understand that at a time one key is passed to reducer instance with iterative values, but still bit confused about reducer task?

Can anyone please help here?

Comment: Can you tell what is the key that you are passing from Mapper to Reducer. Give us some input data details

Comment: @aviral: Key formation is bit complex here.We have some data which we are parsing in mapper and forming key.After that we convert those keys into byte object before sending it to reducer.So even though if i paste sample key , it will be of no use.

Comment: the problem here is that you need to understand your input data. If you are parsing your values to byte object (Hadoop data type equivalent is ?) ,then maybe most of your keys are same and are getting parsed to the same byte object and thus going to the same reducer.